# Why shouldn't you change the size of a binary file?

Tags: executable, hex-editors

When I use HxD to modify a part of a file, it warns me about changing the size of the binary. What happens when you change the size of the exe file or other hex file that causes it to break?

Comment: That depends entirely on who is using the file. Binary executables, though, probably have hard-coded offsets for jump instructions that may not work if you move the target to a new offset.

Comment: Hackerz just ain't what they used to be. :D

Comment: @chepner Okay! Thanks that's exactly what I was wondering. So it would be like offsetting data on your RAM which would lead to terrible things.